# How to "copy-paste" important commands?

Tags: shell, copy-paste, ubuntu-server

This question is *not* about the `cp` command.

I don't have a mouse nor a GUI installed on an Ubuntu server, but I would like to save some commands in a file so I can reuse them later.

Is my only choice to retype them in a file (using Vi/Nano/whatever), or is there a way to copy them?

Comment: Commands in a file? Isn't that a shell script for?

Comment: Yes, I would like to create shell script based on commands (quite long) that I ve already used, and wonder if there is a better way to type them again to create the sh file, or if there is some way to put them in a shell script

Comment: This comment is on a different subject, but I am writing here because [this seems to be the only way to talk to a user except chat](http://meta.superuser.com/a/7722/162573). You gave me a short answer to one of my questions (on playing DVD with external subs) but then you have deleted it. I investigated your answer and found that VLC worked if the video output is changed to OpenGL. I want to give you credit and show you the solution: [here](http://superuser.com/a/719335/162573).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is of course also bash's history mechanism.  If enabled, bash will keep a file  `~/.bash_history` which contains all command lines that you entered, up to a maximum number of entries.

There's also the `fc` command to browse the history without looking through the file, for instance `fc -l 1 | fgrep echo` to list all history lines containing `echo` anywhere.

All of this of course can be configured:

- `HISTFILE` sets the name of the history file, instead of `~/bash_history`
- `HISTSIZE` sets the maximum number of entries that are kept in the history (defaults to 500).
- `HISTCONTROL` allows some fine tuning about what is kept in the history and what not.  By setting `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` duplicate entries are kept only once, and you can prevent single command lines from showing up in the history by prepending a space (e.g.  `ls` instead of `ls`).

I like to keep `HISTSIZE` as large as I can without slowing down my machine, that's typically around 50000 or so before it gets noticeable.  This way I can go back for months if I don't remember that one difficult pipeline or whatever and I need it again.

*( I'm not using bash myself, only zsh, but from what I gather from the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) the mechanism is similar.  Someone please correct me if I got the details wrong. )*

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Let s say you have some big command, add echo before the command, and redirect stdout to a file.

Example for the command

```
someapp -wich have a lot of arguments and -is boring -to type
```

Type

```
echo someapp -wich have a lot of arguments and -is boring -to type > file.sh
```

It will create file.sh which contain the command

Comment: also >> will append the output to an existing file. > will overwrite any existing file.

Comment: If your command contains wildcards (e.g., `cat *.txt`), the wildcard will be expanded when you do the `echo` and so you will capture `cat laundry.txt shopping.txt` (for example) in your `file.sh`. You might do better with the `history` command.

Answer (score 0):

What you want, should/could be done with the command [alias](http://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/alias.html).

You could create separate files for each complex command but this is just what `alias` is for.

You do

```
alias sa='someapp -wich have a lot of arguments and -is boring -to type'
```

and when you type `sa` + <kbd>enter</kbd> on the prompt it will run your program with arguments.

To survive a restart of `bash` you need to add them to `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.kshrc` or whatever shell you use).

Mine looks like this:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

So you could add your `alias`-line there.